# Bounded denominators for modular forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I recently saw a conjecture that a modular form is a congruence modular form if and only if it has bounded denominators. I wonder if one direction or the other is already known to be true?

EDIT: For completeness, here is the answer I received at Math Overflow when I asked a while back.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59498/bounded-denominators-for-modular-forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am familiar with this conjecture, specifically for cusp forms.

It is known that every cusp form of a congruence subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with algebraic Fourier coefficients has bounded denominators.  This is because we can decompose the space of weight $k$ cuspforms of a congruence subgroup into eigenforms (newforms and pushups of newforms), which have algebraically integral Fourier coefficients.  Then any form with algebraic Fourier coefficients is just a linear combination of these eigenforms over algebraic numbers, and so must have bounded denominators.

There are several examples of noncongruence cusp forms which are $n$<sup>th</sup> roots of congruence cusp forms, which means their expansions have arbitrarily large powers of $n$ in the denominator.  But there is no general method yet for showing that every genuinely noncongruence cusp form has unbounded denominators.

Comment: Thanks for the help, once again.

Comment: @JonsasKibelbek Is there consequences to the bounded determinants iff congruence modular forms conjecture?

Answer (score 1):

The unbounded denominators conjecture was proven in the affirmative and is now a theorem.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.09040

https://www.quantamagazine.org/long-sought-math-proof-unlocks-more-mysterious-modular-forms-20230309/

Basically, the authors proved that there was an upper bound of possible noncongruence modular forms with bounded denominators, and if one existed, it would imply the existence of so many other such forms that it would exceed the upper bound.